# flash videos not playing in Firefox or in Chromium browser in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: adobe

I have installed Adobe Flash Player in Firefox and also in Chromium browser
, but still I'm unable to see flash videos, viz. Hotstar in Ubuntu 16.04 (32 bit). But same Firefox is playing flash videos in Windows 7 (32 bit) after installing Adobe Flash Player. How to fix it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't install [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com)? It comes with flash built in

Comment: Chromium Browser is already installed. But still I'm unable to see flash videos.

Comment: You have [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/) installed. This is a free open source web browser made by Google. However you can also install [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com), which is a free but not open source web browser made by Google, with extra features like the latest Flash Player preinstalled.
See [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/202825/what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-chromium-and-chrome/) for more info